# Count the frequence of each word of my list in a given string

Tags: python, count, text-files

i want to sum the count of the frequency of each word of my list In a string.
How can i do ?
Details:

```
list = ['Apple', 'Mango' ,'Orange','p[éeêè]t[s]' ]
text = 'I have Apple and mood today, This morning i ate mango and pret then Orange'
```

In this case i want to return 4.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  what is your question?

Comment: Maybe spend some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you a feel for the tolls Python has to help you solve your problem.

Comment: Try to avoid naming variables after types. As in, don't name it `list`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.count` to `sum` with a generator expression.

```
>>> words = ['Apple', 'Mango', 'Orange' ]
>>> text = 'I have Apple and Mango mood today, This morning i ate Mango and then Orange'
>>> sum(text.count(word) for word in words)
4
```

Comment: thank you . but in this case if i wrote mango with little m it doesn't work .. And in my list of w*ord i have regex like = p[éeêè]t[s]|

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import re
len([word for word in text.split() if any(re.match(pattern, word) for pattern in list)])
```

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work for my case. i have edited my question .

Comment: Ah, you didn't mention that they were regex patterns. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the `frequency` of each word using a `dict` comprehsnion,
And then, `sum` the `values` to get the total,

```
>>> list_
['Apple', 'Mango', 'Orange']
>>> text
'I have Apple and Mango mood today, This morning i ate Mango and then Orange'
>>> y = {x: text.count(x) for x in list_}
>>> y
{'Orange': 1, 'Mango': 2, 'Apple': 1}
>>> sum(y.values())
4
```

After the questions is changed, you need something like this,

```
>>> import re
>>> list_ = ['Apple', 'Mango' ,'Orange', 'pr[éeêè]t[s]?' ]
>>> text
'I have Apple and mood today, This morning i ate mango and pret then Orange'
>>> re.findall(r'|'.join(list_), text)
['Apple', 'pret', 'Orange']
>>> len(re.findall(r'|'.join(list_), text))
3
```

And if you need the `frequencies` of each `word`, then use the `Counter` from the `collections` module,

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(re.findall(r'|'.join(list_), text))
Counter({'Orange': 1, 'pret': 1, 'Apple': 1})
```

And for case `insensitive` search,

```
>>> Counter(re.findall(r'|'.join(list_).lower(), text.lower()))
Counter({'orange': 1, 'pret': 1, 'mango': 1, 'apple': 1})
>>> d = Counter(re.findall(r'|'.join(list_).lower(), text.lower()))
>>> sum(d.values())
4
```

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work for my case. i have edited my question

Comment: What is `'p[éeêè]t[s]'` ?

Comment: a regex . if have pret or prét i count it also

Comment: how can i do ? then

Comment: i have to search words in regex also

Comment: Updated the answer. And changed the `list` of items to have correct `regex`. And don't use `list` as a user variables. Don't use builtin vars for user variables

Answer (score 0):

You can convert text to list and then loop through each word in this list. Increment a counter if word is in your list:

```
words = ['Apple', 'Mango', 'Orange' ]
text = 'I have Apple and Mango mood today, This morning i ate Mango and then Orange'

textlist = text.split(" ")  # split text to words;
counter = 0
for word in textlist:
    if word in words:
        counter+=1 
print(counter)
```

Output:

```
4
```

In following code has been added to remove comma and periods at end of words:

```
textlist = text.split(" ")
print(textlist)
counter = 0
for word in textlist:
    if word[-1] in [',','.']:  # if last character is comma or period
        word = word[:-1]       # remove last character
    if word in words:
        counter+=1 
print(counter)
```